# OnClick button ,create a layer in the same form. Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I m very new to Android.

I want to create a dynamic OnClick button functionality.

[image]

OnClick of "+" above , it should create a other layer , like this below.

[image]

My confusion , my entire design UI is in layout.xml.

How we can we include another layer in our UI on OnClick of "+" button.

Any input would be helpful.

Thanks !!!

Comment: How about having a listview of items composed of EditText - Spinner - + Button? Whenever you press the button you update your data model and refresh the ui.

Comment: It is simple enough. Save that particular row layout in it's own file and use the LayoutInflater to "inflate" a new row whenever the `+` is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your XML have one `Vertical Linear Layout` to add and remove `EditTexts` at runtime, Here I have shown you code I have used in my demos. To handle and maintain the usage.

Onclick of your Add and Minus button click

```
    public void onClick(View view) {
        super.onClick(view);
        switch (view.getId()) {

        case R.id.btnadd:
            createTextview(counter);
            counter++;
            if (counter > 3) {
                btnAdd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnRemove.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.btnremove:
            removeView(counter);
            txtoption[counter - 1] = null;
            counter--;
            if (counter < 3) {
                btnAdd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnRemove.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            break;
        }
    }
```

Functions to create and remove view

```
private void createTextview(int index) {
    txtoption[index] = new EditText(this);
    txtoption[index].setSingleLine(true);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    param.bottomMargin = 10;
    txtoption[index].setLayoutParams(param);
    txtoption[index].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textbox);
    txtoption[index].setTypeface(ttfDroidSherif);
    lnpolloptions.addView(txtoption[index]);

}

private void removeView(int index) {
    lnpolloptions.removeView(txtoption[index - 1]);
}
```

Your vertical LinearLayout to contain all the edittext childs

```
LinearLayout lnpolloptions = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lnpolloptions);
```

Arrays of edittext to be created of removed at runtime

```
private EditText[] txtoption = new EditText[4];
```

Onclick of submit to get value from each textbox

```
            int length = txtoption.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (txtoption[i] != null) {
                    Log.i("Value",""+txtoption[i].getText());
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this programatically. XML is for static layouts.

Excuse my pseudo Android:

```
private LinearLayout root;

public void onCreate(Bundle b){

    LinearLayout root = new LinearLayout(this);

    root.addChild(createGlucoseReadingView());

    setContentView(root);

}

private View createGlucoseReadingView() {
   LinearLayout glucoseRoot = new LinearLayout(this);
   glucoseRoot.addChild(new TextView(this));
   return glucoseRoot;
}

public void onPlusClick(View button){
   root.addChild(createGlucoseReadingView());
}
```

Something along those lines, I've obviosuly left out formatting and adding the layout params to the views, but you get the idea.

Comment: +1 for taking out time and writing an answer on new year's eve... Happy new year.!!